# Using ftp-deploy with load-grunt-tasks causes errors

Tags: deployment, ftp, gruntjs

I've split my Gruntfile into multiple files using `load-grunt-tasks` but seem to get an error when using ftp-deploy. I've tried some different things, but I reason that the hyphen (-) in the "ftp-deploy" might cause problems.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Running "ftp-deploy:theme" (ftp-deploy) task
Verifying property ftp-deploy.theme exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "ftp-deploy.theme" missing. Use --force to continue.
```

When running:

```
grunt "ftp-deploy:theme" --verbose
```

My ftp-deploy script looks as follows:

```
# FTP DEPLOY
# -------
module.exports =

  'ftp-deploy': 
    theme:
      auth:
        host: 'host.com'
        port: 21
        authKey: 'key'
      src: 'drupal/sites/all/themes/theme_name'
      dest: 'www/host.com/sites/all/themes/theme_name'
```

I've tried running it without incapsulating it inside the "theme:" object which works, but is essentially not what I want to do as I have different folders I want to transfer.

Any ideas to what a solution might be?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

```
'ftp-deploy':
```

Should of course not be included in the file.